# Filtering a list of two-element sublists with a list comprehension

Tags: python

I have a list of lists

```
input = [[2,13],[5,3],[10,8],[13,4],[15,0],[17,10],[20,5],[25,9],[28,7],[31,0]]
```

I want to write a list comprehension where for the `[a,b]` pairs above I get the pairs where `b > a`. In the above example that would be `[2,13]`.

My attempt

```
x = [[item[i],[j]] for item in inputArray if j>i]
```

produces a `NameError`

```
NameError: name 'j' is not defined`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your attempt is that you never tell Python what `i` and `j` are supposed to be. The check `j > i` cannot be computed and the list `[item[i],[j]]` can't be built without that information.

You can issue

```
>>> inp = [[2,13],[5,3],[10,8],[13,4],[15,0],[17,10],[20,5],[25,9],[28,7],[31,0]]
>>> [[a, b] for a, b in inp if b > a]
[[2, 13]]
```

This solution does not produce a `NameError` because `for a, b in inp` tells Python to iterate over the elements of `inp` (two-element sublists) and in each iteration assign the name `a` to the first element of a sublist and the name `b` to the second element.

I used the name `inp` instead of `input` because the latter is already taken by a builtin function for getting user input.

*Explanation of the list comprehension*

The comprehension is equivalent to

```
>>> result = []
>>> for a, b in inp:
...     if b > a:
...         result.append([a, b])
... 
>>> result
[[2, 13]]
```

Every two-element list in `inp` is unpacked into the variables `a` and `b`. If the filter condition `b > a` is `True`, then a list `[a, b]` is built and included in the final result.

If you don't want to use unpacking, you can also index into the sublists of `inp` like this:

```
>>> [sub[:] for sub in inp if sub[1] > sub[0]]
[[2, 13]]
```

Taking a full slice of `sub` via `sub[:]` ensures that like in the other solutions presented so far, the filtered result stores (shallow) copies of the sublists of `inp`. If copying it not necessary, you can omit the `[:]`.

This code does not produce a `NameError` because `for sub in inp` tells Python to iterate over `inp` and in each iteration assign the name `sub` to the next sublist. In addition, explicit numbers (`0` and `1`) are used for the indices.

Personally, I prefer the solution with unpacking. It is easier to read and will run even if the elements of `inp` don't support indexing, but are iterables from which two elements can be extracted.

Comment: Thank you! for explaining and editing my post as well. I will ask questions like that from next time.

Answer (score 1):

You should unpack each pair into the `i`, `j` variables, and then you can compare them:

```
x = [[i, j] for i,j in inputList if j > i]
```

*(note I have renamed `inputArray`, `inputList`)*

---

Or without unpacking:

```
x = [item for item in inputList if item[1] > item[0]]
```